# Display collection form on page load in Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin, sonata

Is there an option or a known way to display collection form on page load instead of clicking on "add" button in order to display it ?

I trigger a click event on page load but its not the expected behavior..

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I achieved what I wanted by setting a default collection array on my form field, each Entity object in array imbricates a form, since I needed to display 3 form on page load I instanciated 3 entity, quite logic when I think of it now but a dedicated option could be nice though.

```
->add('details', CollectionType::class, [
            'data' => [new OfferDetail(), new OfferDetail(), new OfferDetail()],
            'label' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'type_options' => [
                'delete' => false,
            ],
        ], [
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table'
        ])
```